# Display a different message depending on date of the week

Tags: ios, swift, date, time

For a project I was working on I wanted to create an app that displays a different text depending on the day of the week, (ex, monday tuesday, wednesday, etc), however I do not know what to do from here. Any help would be much appreciated since I am new too coding.
(since the following code does not seem to function as intended.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let date = Date()
        let calendar = Calendar.current

        let hour = calendar.component(.hour, from: date)
        let minutes = calendar.component(.minute, from: date)
        let seconds = calendar.component(.second, from: date)

        let day = calendar.component(.day, from: date)
        let month = calendar.component(.month, from: date)
        let year = calendar.component(.year, from: date)

        if day = 21 {
            label.text = "not comming today"
        }
        else if day = 22 {
            label.text = "not comming today"
        }
        else if day = 23 {
            label.text = "is comming today"
        }
    }    

}
```

Comment: What you want is `NSCalendarUnitWeekday`.

Comment: That code won't even compile... You are trying to assign a value to a constant in the `if` clauses instead of comparing it using the comparison operator(`==`). Moreover, it seems you want to use `let dayOfTheWeek = calendar.component(.weekday, from: date)`, which returns you the position of the day in the week.

Comment: I tried doing so, however when trying to run it, I received the error message "Thread 1 error SIGABRT", and it does not display the message...

Answer (score 1):

You need the `weekday` component

```
let weekday = calendar.component(.weekday, from: date)
switch weekday {
  case 1: print("It's Sunday")
  case 2: print("It's Monday")
  ...
  case 7: print("It's Saturday")
  default: break
}
```

Comment: I tried doing so; However, the following did not seem to work:     @IBOutlet weak var MYLABEL: UILabel!
    
        
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            let date = Date()
            let calendar = Calendar.current
            
            let dayOfTheWeek = calendar.component(.weekday, from: date)
            
            if dayOfTheWeek == 4 {
                self.MYLABEL.text = "hello4"
            }
            else if dayOfTheWeek == 5 {
                 self.MYLABEL.text = "hello5"
            }
        }

Comment: The code to get the weekday does not cause the issue.

Comment: If your code crashes connect the label in Interface Builder.

Comment: every time I try running it, it just displays Thread 1: signal SIGABRT, and i do not know why

Comment: Once again, most likely the outlet is not connected

Comment: +1 @vadian and once again, do you have any error message in console? Can you show it? Optional nil value found or something? Because the code provided by vadian shouldn't create that crash.

Comment: i get this error message in the console: 2017-12-21 12:36:20.553791-0200 h[6117:434873] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<h.ViewController 0x7fe7a2d070d0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key label.' libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb) 
*** First throw call stack:

Comment: I reposted the code here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47927132/error-sigabrt-strand-1?noredirect=1#comment82822450_47927132

Comment: In the question the `UILabel` is named `label` in the comment `MYLABEL`. If you rename an outlet in code you have to disconnect and reconnect it in Interface Builder (unless you use the Xcode 9 *Refactor* function)

Comment: `'[<h.ViewController 0x7fe7a2d070d0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key label`: Well, that's a well known error already explained on StackOverflow. You need to do some research by yourself too.